# how do i remove a certificate from .exe or .appx

Tags: certificate, exe, appx

In sign tool I'm getting the error: bad executable.

I'm sure this has something to do with the application already being signed.
How do I remove the signature from the application.
I made it by unreal and I've heard unreal automatically signs the app on export.

I also heard if you change the extension to .zip, and then back to .exe or .appx, it will remove the certificate. But I tried that and had no luck.

By the way I don't use visual studio is there an straight forward way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[This will help.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=2508061#post2508061) It is a utility called delcert with soure code on xdadevelopers. It removes digital signatures (Authenticode) from executable files.

Also check that you are running the correct version of the signing tool (32/64 bit) for the executable you need to sign.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. Delcert removes the certificate but im still getting the same error of bad executable. My app is a 32 bit so im using the 32 bit sign tool

Comment: Is your unreal up to date?

Comment: Im using the latest version

Answer (score 0):

For me, the delcert tool left some zero bytes at the end of the file. I have removed them with frhed and it worked for me.